# File options menu above left Taskbar has disappeared: Linux 16.04

Tags: menu

The Files menu above the left Taskbar has disappeared quite arbitrarily so that when I open one of my data files I am no longer able to access items such as "Create new folder".    Menus for other programmes, i.e. Libre Office, etc. are still in place.    I have searched Q&As on this forum and have tried some of the "fixes", but to no avail.  I am not technically brilliant with Ubuntu as I have used Windows all  my working life, so I would be very grateful if someone could give me an idiot guide on how to restore this menu. Many thanks.

Comment: Has the menu disappeared in a specific application you are running? Have you changed any of the application's configuration files? Are you running the application in full screen mode? Try right clicking the top bar to see if an option to display the menu is available.

Comment: I wasn't running an application, just trying to open a new folder in one of my data files.  I brought up the subject file onto Desktop (not full screen mode) and usually when I want to open a new folder I can do this from the Menu Bar, but no options are now available.   It merely says "Files".  I haven't changed any configurations.   I right clicked the top bar.  There are no options to display the menu  but there is an option to open a new folder, so I have done this and kept an untitled, empty folder on the Desktop.  It is a workaround, but not brilliant. I would like to have the menu back.